# How can serial data be sent over a USB port to a microcontroller?

Tags: linux, serialization, go, usb, microcontroller

I'm designing a system that has a linux machine communicating serially with a microcontroller over a USB to RS-485 interface. I'd like to do this in Go if possible.

How can I programmatically send data over the linux machine's USB port?

Comment: Other than using one of the several Go libraries out there for talking with serial ports?

Comment: I'm specifically looking to send data over the USB port. Maybe a mention of at least one of these Go libraries would be useful?

Comment: [godoc](http://godoc.org/?q=usb)

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware of that site.

Comment: If you have a USB-UART bridge you talk over serial, not USB. The OS handles the USB side of things.

Comment: Yeah the cable I have has a UART converter built in. I'll try to use one of the many packages in the search provided by thwd

Comment: If I'm using a USB-UART bridge, I would still need to use one of these packages to send data over the USB port, right? Sorry, I'm not familiar with all of this. @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: No. The OS handles the USB part, and presents a serial port.